# CSV Reader converts numbers to decimals when held as strings

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a CSV file that holds both words and numbers but they are all read in as strings. My CSV file looks something like this:

```
Hello,50,Banana,100,Dog,80
```

When read in with the CSV Reader, all of the numbers are still held as strings but are changed to 50.0, 100.0, and 80.0. Does anyone know why this is and how to get rid of it?

Here is the code I am using (The CSV file is flipped from how it normally is this is why I used this algorithm:

```
with open(csvFinal) as file:
        for line in csv.reader(file):
            if len(line) > 0 and re.search("Token\d", line[1]):
                if line[-1] == "":
                    csvDict[line[1]] = line[2:-1]
                else:
                    csvDict[line[1]] = line[2:]
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that you are using to read the csv file?

Comment: have you tried `int( variable)` ?

Comment: @boobanos I have IP addresses stored as well so if I typecasted everything to an integer would that mess them up because they have decimals?

Comment: @DylanNewman can you provide a line from your csv file?

Comment: @boobanos "Interface", "", "", "", "","50", "123.12.123.123" When read into my program the 50 is converted to 50.0 but still held in a string

Comment: Nothing in the code you show would perform that conversion.

Comment: Could it have something to do with converting an excel file into a CSV? Does excel hold all values as floats?

Answer (score 0):

By reference:

[CSV Reader Manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

> csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams) Return a reader
>   object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile. csvfile can
>   be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a
>   string

and

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No
>   automatic data type conversion is performed unless the
>   QUOTE_NONNUMERIC format option is specified (in which case unquoted
>   fields are transformed into floats).

**By default, all results are string and UNLESS you use quote, no cast data fill perform.**

Using the given example inside a .csv:

```
Hello,50,Banana,100,Dog,80
```

The simple code:

```
import csv

with open('your_file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        for cell in row:
            print(cell, type(cell))
```

Will return:

```
Hello <class 'str'>                                                                                                                            
50 <class 'str'>                                                                                                                           
Banana <class 'str'>                                                                                                                       
100 <class 'str'>                                                                                                                          
Dog <class 'str'>                                                                                                                          
80 <class 'str'>
```